# How can I execute groovy scripts in an isolated classloader?

Tags: java, groovy, classloader, urlclassloader, groovyclassloader

I'm trying to run groovy scripts in an isolated classloader so that they are not executed in the context of the calling class' dependencies.

```
    Path log4j = Paths.get("..../lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar");
    Path groovy = Paths.get("..../lib/groovy-all-2.1.3.jar");
    RootLoader rootLoader = new RootLoader(new URL[] { log4j.toUri().toURL(), groovy.toUri().toURL() }, null);
    GroovyScriptEngine engine = new GroovyScriptEngine(".../src/main/resources", rootLoader);
    engine.run("Standalone.groovy", "");
```

***Standalone.groovy***:

```
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator
import org.apache.log4j.Logger

Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass())
BasicConfigurator.configure()
logger.info("hello world")
```

***`pom.xml` excerpt***:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any variation on the above that I've tried always results in

```
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Failed to create Script instance for class: class Standalone. Reason: java.lang.ClassCastException: Standalone cannot be cast to groovy.lang.GroovyObject
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.createScript(InvokerHelper.java:443)
    at groovy.util.GroovyScriptEngine.createScript(GroovyScriptEngine.java:564)
    at groovy.util.GroovyScriptEngine.run(GroovyScriptEngine.java:551)
    at groovy.util.GroovyScriptEngine.run(GroovyScriptEngine.java:537)
```

I've tracked this back to `groovy.util.GroovyScriptEngine#loadScriptByName` where the script is parsed into a `Class<T>`, where T is the name of the script itself.

My theory is that this is caused by binary incompatibility between the groovy runtime running in the calling class and the groovy runtime running in a standalone class loader, due to the way groovy creates synthetic classes out of scripts through reflection.

Any ideas about how this can be accomplished?

Comment: I would try to instantiate the GroovyScriptEngine too from that classloader. It looks the generated classes are not 100% isolated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to create `GroovyScriptEngine` not directly but through `rootLoader.loadClass()` and call `engine.run` through reflection.